# How to add php in html option tag?

Tags: php, html

I want to add values in option tag from sql database with the help of php. I have tried it but it is not showing anything
**Here is my code which I have tried**

```
<form action="addsubcategory.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="sub_category" placeholder="Add sub category">
<?php
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM product_category");
echo '<select name="testSelect" id="testId">';

//Here is the problem

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
echo '<option value="'.$record['category_name'].'">' .  "</option";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
 </form>
```

Comment: Do you see a select field? Add a value which should be shown, right after `<option>`

Comment: You forget > in closing option tag like </option> and also add value which show in front end

Comment: Ok... I have tried it.. But all the values are shown in single 'option'

Comment: It solved my problem... Thanx @ManinderpreetSingh

Comment: Welcome :) @imran hasan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
   echo '<option value="'.$record['category_name'].'">'.$record['category_name'].' "</option">';
```

Answer (score 4):

Where you have this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$record['category_name'].'">' .  "</option";
```

You need this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$record['category_name'].'">' .  "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only added value to option tag.

```
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
echo '<option value="'.$record['category_name'].'">' .  "</option";
}
```

instead of above code you should use:

```
       while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo '<option value='.$record["category_name"].'>'. $record["category_name"] .'</option>';
}
```

Now above code will add value and text in option tag. Text to view and value to set or get value from db.